# Is there any effect on bonds formation and reactants due to a reaction in adiabatic calorimeter

Tags: thermodynamics, calorimetry

Is there any effect on reactants and bond formation due to a reaction going on a adiabatic calorimeter.We know enthalpy of a reaction should be measured at constant temperature but in adiabatic calorimeter every second the temperature of the chemical solution keeps on changing.

Comment: How did you plan to measure reaction enthalpy, if temperature in  calorimeter was constant ? Ideally the constant temperature is meant for the environment, so temperature of calorimeter does not have externally caused drift.

Comment: @Poutnik You can measure reaction enthalpy at constant T using isothermal heat flow calorimetry.

Comment: Actually, that is an industry-standard type of calorimetry.

Comment: @theorist Well, it could be, but it would have indeed an interesting setting and would not be adiabatic. Also I am not sure anyone using such an equipment would ask the above question.